# as3 array remove by index

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, indexing

I have an array 'cat', 'dog', 'budgie'

and want to remove the item by index.

At the moment I have

```
function removeit(myindex) {
    animals[myindex] = animals.pop()
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `animals[myindex] = null`? What do you want the end result to be?

Comment: if I pass in 'cat I want it to be, 'dog', budgie'. I ma remove the item I am passing to the function

Comment: people will be more inclined to help you in the future if you mark answers as correct :)

Answer (score 34):

You want splice

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29

Array.splice(starting point, remove count);

```
 var newArray:Array = myArray.splice(2, 1); //this removes whatever is at index 2 and returns it in a new array.
```

Change your function to

```
function removeit(myindex) {
    animals.splice(myindex, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When using Flash Player 19+ or AIR 19+, you can use

```
myArray.removeAt(myIndex); // removes the element at the specified index, modifying the array without making a copy
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#removeAt()