# Array won't refresh itself after removeChild

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

There is an array of objects. I'm trying to `removeChild` an object from that array like below. `removeChild` works fine but the array won't refresh itself after removing uppest object. As you can see in below, i tried to `trace` array items out.

Firstly, array has three items, obviously the `myArray.length` must be 3.
After removing a child, `myArray.length` must be 2, but it get 3 (Wrong).

```
removeChild(myArray[currShape]);
trace(myArray);
```

Please tell me what am i missing here.

Comment: This is advanced stuff but I'll say it anyway. Even if you remove the elements from the array using `splice`, the objects will still be "alive". That's because practically all objects in AS3 are just pointers to the real objects stored in memory. Vars in AS3 are just references to the real objects that you never actually interact with. That's why even if you remove the object from the array, it will still be rendered in the display list.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using ActionScript, removeChild() only serves to take objects off the stage. It doesn't take things out of an array. You have to take the object out of the array manually in another statement.

Comment: Thank you, please tell me how do i take the object out with another statement ?

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089806/as3-array-remove-by-index

Comment: First arg is index to start splicing at, second is how many items to splice out

Comment: Just to clarify, the array is the container of the objects themselves.  `removeChild` is to remove `displayObjects` from the display list, which is a way of saying to remove objects from the render mechanism. If this is not crystal clear to you, you should read about the display list.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
removeChild(myArray.splice(currShape,1));
```

This removes the entry from the array and returns that entry that will be used to remove it from the stage.

Comment: This is actually not going to work because splice returns an Array containing the object spliced, not a DisplayObject. You would need to add a pop to make that work. ie `removeChild(myArray.splice(currShape,1).pop());`